# How to show a section or a div outside of the header, exactly under the sticky menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show a section while hovering a menu item on a sticky menu. So that wherever in the page I am, The section should be seen exactly under the sticky menu.

I tried putting the section inside the header. But when I scroll while hovering, the section behaves as sticky menu itself.
How can I hide the section when I scroll? Creating a parallax like effect.

```
//HTML
<header role="banner" class="stickyheader">//sticky
    <nav class="row main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <ul id="primary-menu">
                    <li>1</li>
                    <li>2</li>
                    <li>3</li>
            </ul>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->

    <section class="hiddensection">//section to show
                    show uo when hovering menu item 3....
                    //height:500px

    </section>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scroll event and hide it whenever the page is scrolled.

```
window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
document.getElementByClassName(".hiddensection").style.display = "none";
} else {
document.getElementByClassName(".hiddensection").style.display= "block";
}
prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```